# How to see and track kernel changes in linux related to a subsystem say I2C

Tags: linux-kernel, porting, i2c

Something in kernel is bugging me. 
As of now the of_* support for i2c devices are somewhat not acceptable to me. 
There was a probe_new* function added, but now I can't see that and I am using older probe.
The kernel that I have (4.4.127), is customised for Beaglebone black and taken from Robert C nelson github repository.

So I want to know if someone have done any improvement in I2C ,so I search and get this,

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9395089/

Here I see that its done in 2016. As my kernel is newer 4.4.127 and also I have 4.9 too I know it should have that patch.

But its not there. I checked the files and the patch is not there.
So what happened? Surely in between there were changes done and its possible that this particular change was removed/modified.
I try to take the newest kernel from https://www.kernel.org/ and it have removed/added many files from drivers/i2c/ 
Now porting the changes to my kernel version is a daunting task as too many files/structures are changed.

So How do I get to see these changes?

How I can improve to understand linux from release to release?

How can I start to port my kernel for I2C newest changes?

I think its a broad question, but any kernel expert can tell me what should I have done or look in particular places to gain such understanding.

Comment: 1. You need to follow subsystem tree, i.e. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/wsa/linux.git/. 2. You need to follow I2C and / or another mailing list and participate in the contributions (you can start from testing others' patches). 3. Easiest way is to switch to most recent LTS release.

Comment: I took 4.14 kernel, used everything but the driver's probe is never called. I guess there is a bug in kernel for loading of modules.

Comment: There are stable releases of that version. Take the last one.

Answer (score 0):

https://marc.info/?l=linux-i2c

Here I can see all changes done in I2C subsystem.

Comment: Nope. These are __proposed__ changes, and not unconditionally __done__ ones.

Comment: So thats why I think I need to know what changes are merged and mainline. I get this list which tells nothing about its purpose, so I thought it is all the changes done.

Comment: See my comment to the post.

Comment: Yes I got it.Thanks.